# merging git with vim without the automerged MERGED

Tags: vim, git, merge

I want to use vim (fugitive possibly) to merge my conflicts, but I hate the automerged conflict markers.  I'm looking for something like

```
|-------------------------------|
|         |          |          |
| LOCAL   | HEAD     |   REMOTE |
|         |          |          |
|-------------------------------|
|                               |
|    clean head to merge        |
|       changes into            |
|-------------------------------|
```

How do I set this up?

Comment: Does [this link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/A_better_Vimdiff_Git_mergetool) help? Or [this one](http://www.toofishes.net/blog/three-way-merging-git-using-vim/)?

Answer (score 1):

To always turn off conflict markers, you can configure the binary merge algorithm ([source](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/3/8/1113104)):

```
$ git config merge.default binary
```

Alternatively, the index has all different versions; just override your working copy with what you want:

```
$ git checkout --ours <filename>
$ git checkout --theirs <filename>
$ git checkout-index -f --stage=1 <filename>    # for the base
```

(With *Fugitive* you can do this directly from within Vim.)

Answer (score 0):

I use Fugitive. The amazing vim cast on [resolving merge conflicts with vimdiff + Fugitive](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-resolving-merge-conflicts-with-vimdiff/) is what I use repeatedly every time I forget how to do this.

1. You open up a conflicted file and type `:Gvdiff` (this gives you a vertical split as you want)
2. You use `:diffput` (or just `dp`) to push code from local/remote windows to HEAD
3. Once you're happy with the changes type `:Gwrite` and it will close the diff window and add the file to the Git index ready for the commit